# replace a character attribute with a numerical value R

Tags: r, data-mining, gsub

I have a Char attribute called **Class**. In this column I have two data values (negative and positive). I want to change this value from **Negative** to **0** and **Positive** to **1**

Problem is I can change the column to numeric but it removes all the data to N/A.

How do I code it so I do the following:

Change the Class attribute from char to numeric & change the data (negative = 0 & Positive - 1)

This is what i got but as mentioned it makes the data null:

```
CW_ModelDevelopment$Class <- as.numeric(CW_ModelDevelopment$Class)
```

I was using GSUB to remove it and replace it with but it would not work as the Class currently is Character not numerical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the code to a logical expression (`== 'Positive'`) and then coerce to `integer` with `as.integer`  so that `TRUE -> 1` and `FALSE -> 0`

```
CW_ModelDevelopment$Class<- as.integer(CW_ModeDevelopment$Class == 'Positive')
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I need it to be numerical so I just ran the original script (CW_ModelDevelopment$Class<-as.numeric(CW_ModelDevelopment$Class)). Thank you very much. CAn I just as why does it allow the change to interger and not numerical?